# Excel: Specify sheetname in another cell for countif formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-indirect

My intention is to use the indirect formula. Here is the code I want to edit:

```
=COUNTIF('sheetname'!R:R;"x")
```

This code gives a #ref! error:

```
=INDIRECT("COUNTIF('"&D85&"'!R:R;"&B98&")")
```

Cell D85 contains `sheetname` and B98 contains `"x"`.
My version of Excel needs ; in formulas instead of ,.

Thanks in advance for your expertise and time.

Comment: You put `indirect` inside `countif`, not the other way round.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this formula:

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&D85&"'!R:R");B98)
```

Comment: Dear Philippe.H, this formula results in 0 (when it should be 9). Any idea how that happened? I don't understand why you didn't put B98 inside the indirect?

Comment: Then your criteria needs some help.

Comment: It means that you do not have a match, check your criteria and compare with what you have in row RR. You use the Indirect function if you want to convert a string into a reference. Not needed for B98 in your case.

Comment: Try putting in cell B98 an x surrounded by * (wildcard). Does it make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

With some modification it works, I hope this is a good compromise for you. The modified formula is

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT(E1); F1)
```

and in this case that E1 should contain something like

```
''sheetname'!R:R
```

(See the double apostrophes at the beginning.)
F1 should contain the "X" or other value you want to count.

Comment: Sorry. F1 contains the "x" the OP wanted to count

Answer (score 0):

My read on [`Indirect`](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/INDIRECT-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd) says that it simply uses the cell reference contained in the cell you specify in the function:

```
Indirect( cellContainingReference )
```

In this case, you don't need to specify the second parameter of `Indirect`.

So, using the assumptions:

- `sheetName` is in cell `D85`
- `cellRange` is always `R:R`
- `criteria` for counting is in cell B98 (which does not need `Indirect` to work)
- Your excel uses ';' rather than ','

Your formula for `CountIf` would be:

```
=countif(indirect("'"&D85&"'!R:R"); B98)
```

Comment: For some reason, this formula results in 0, whereas it should be 9 (as in the formula in my question without indirect.) Any idea why that is?

Comment: Yes - either the information supplied in the question is off a bit, or the criteria is typed incorrectly - can you tell us what your criteria is?

Comment: Is "X" in quotes in B98? If so, remove them.